# Child Browser plugin is not working in Cordova 2.3.0 in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have integrated child browser + Google Oauth in Cordova 2.3.0. But child browser plugin not working in iOS.

Is this integration problem?

I have integrated using steps, mentioned in the following link:

- [Google Oauth Integratration](http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery)
- [Child Browser](http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2012/03/installing-the-childbrowser-plugin-for-ios-with-phonegapcordova-1-5/)

Comment: You can use InAppBrowser which is included in phonegap package. Refer to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InAppBrowser which is included in phonegap package. It is introduced in Phonegap/Cordova 2.3.0, so you are good to go.

Refer to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser